# Attempting to reach an IIS server on the same network

Tags: iis-8

I recently installed IIS 8 on my windows 8 desktop machine.  Then to test it out, I typed went to localhost from that computer and the IIS8 logo came up just fine.  Then from my laptop (on the same network) typed in (thecomputerIP):88 but it timed out, unable to find the server.  I also tried variations of that ( just the computer IP, the ip + a directory etc.)

If all I did was install IIS 8 then test it, are there any steps I missed?

Thanks

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious - but did you try port 80 instead of port 88?

Comment: Yep, gets the same error, it's the weirdest thing. Is windows 8 known for having IIS issues at all?

Comment: Not sure - question might be more appropriate for another group though (superuser?)

Comment: Is it possible that my router is blocking ports internally?

Comment: More likely the software router or security software on your win 8 box but I really don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows ships with Windows Firewall, where most ports are blocked.

For the port you choose to open, make that change in Windows Firewall and then you can test again.

Comment: This was it. I tried turning on individual programs through windows firewall but unfortunately I had to entirely shut down WF.  Thanks though